# any cleaner/elegant way to create lists of lists without using 'for' construct?

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a need to create an object to calculate and store 3 sets of power prices (on-peak, off-peak, and a day average) for 14 nodes in a grid for each month of the year for the past two years. I thought that an embedded list data structure would be appropriate (correct me if this isn't optimal).

In any case I'm not a fan of using for loops to create this structure. If there is an elegant way to do this I would be grateful if someone could help steer me in the right direction. I'm trying to practice and improve my coding. Thank you.

```
hb_lz_names <- c("HB_BUSAVG", "HB_HOUSTON", "HB_HUBAVG", "HB_NORTH", "HB_SOUTH", 
"HB_WEST", "LZ_AEN", "LZ_CPS", "LZ_HOUSTON", "LZ_LCRA", "LZ_NORTH", 
"LZ_RAYBN", "LZ_SOUTH", "LZ_WEST")

power_price <- list()
for (i in 1:2){
  power_price[[i]] <- list()
  for (j in 1:12){
    power_price[[i]][[j]] <- list()
    for (k in 1:NROW(hb_lz_names)) {
      power_price[[i]][[j]][[k]] <- list()
      for (l in 1:3){
        power_price[[i]][[j]][[k]][[l]] <- l
      }
      names(power_price[[i]][[j]][[k]]) <- c("on-peak", "off-peak", "average")
    }
    names(power_price[[i]][[j]]) <- hb_lz_names
  }
  names(power_price[[i]]) <- c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug",
                             "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec")
}
names(power_price) <- c("2011", "2012")
```

Comment: What about using `expand.grid`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that for a *regular* (not ragged) data set like this you will be **much** better off using an array:

```
period_names <- c("on-peak", "off-peak", "average")
hb_lz_names <- c("HB_BUSAVG", "HB_HOUSTON", "HB_HUBAVG", "HB_NORTH", "HB_SOUTH", 
"HB_WEST", "LZ_AEN", "LZ_CPS", "LZ_HOUSTON", "LZ_LCRA", "LZ_NORTH", 
"LZ_RAYBN", "LZ_SOUTH", "LZ_WEST")
yrs <- 2011:2012

power.price <- array(1,dim=c(2,12,length(hb_lz_names),length(period_names)))
dimnames(power.price) <- list(year=yrs,month=month.abb,node=hb_lz_names,
                              period=period_names)
```

(Giving names to the *elements* in the `dimnames` list -- i.e. naming your dimensions -- can be a big help in trying to remember the array structure ...)

You can then easily compute averages (or other summary statistics) across the appropriate margins by using `apply`, and convert to long format (for `ggplot` graphics or statistical analysis) using `reshape2::melt` ... in my experience, deeply nested lists are a pain in the butt.

Comment: Thank you very much for the guidance. I actually will be using ggplot and will be doing some stats analysis so this is great info. Thank you @mnel for your suggestion as well.